# Extend UIButton in monotouch

Tags: c#, uikit, uibutton, xamarin.ios

i'm tring to extend UIButton class to add my id property.

How i can do this?

Problem is to create a button you use

```
var button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundRect);
```

so, if i've

```
public class MyButton : UIButton
```

how i can create my button?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyButton : UIButton
{
public MyButton(RectangleF rect) : base(rect) {}

static MyButton FromType(UIButtonType buttonType)
{
    var b = new MyButton (new RectangleF(0, 0, 200, 40));
    b.SetTitle("My Button",UIControlState.Normal);

    //additional customization here

    return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically the same as cvista but using a static factory method to make it cleaner

Comment: i used your code, but there is a compilation error: The type MyButton does not contain a costructor that takes 1 arguments.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would create your button:

```
MyButton button = new MyButton (new RectangleF(0, 0, 250, 37));
button.SetTitle("My Button",UIControlState.Normal);
```

To Create a button of a type you could try:

```
MyButton button = new MyButton (UIButtonType.RoundRect);
```

and see if it returns a button of the correct type which inherits from your MyButton class - but I doubt it. You may have to add the image and size it yourself:

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("action.png");
MyButton button = new MyButton (new RectangleF(0, 0, 250, 37));
button.SetBackgroundImage(image,UIControlState.Normal);
```

Not sure if there's another way but looking at the docs the UIButton.ButtonType is read only and there's no SetType method so you can only set a UIButton class ButtonType property by instantiating it and passing the type into the constructor.

w://

Comment: Please explict MyButton class.
Thanks